# How can I edit a file in real-time?

Tags: neovim, save

I would like to edit a file using Neovim and have changes saved in real-time (changes should be written to the file as I am typing), which will be displayed by [an OBS plugin](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/markdown-source.1764/). Is this possible?

Comment: please explain what you mean with editing in real-time

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I would like to have changes saved as I am editing, with a minimal delay between typing and changes being saved. The changes to the file will then be displayed live using an OBS plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty trivial

```
augroup foobar | au!
    autocmd TextChanged ?* update
augroup end
```

You could also catch `TextChangedI` event but that would be overkill, IMO.